# Round all numbers in sympy object

Tags: python, sympy

I have a  **class 'sympy.core.add.Add'** object which I would like to round all numbers in that object to 2 digits.

**Given:**

2.96652814643838*sin(x) + 3.11758737898895*sin(2*x)

**Desired:**

2.97*sin(x) + 3.12*sin(2*x)

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Rounding to a specified number of decimal places is documented quite well on line and in previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `nfloat` will convert all numbers to a desired number of significant figures, there is no way to globally round numbers in an expression. But `expr.xreplace(Transform(lambda x: x.round(2), lambda x: isinstance(x, Float)))` would work.

```
>>> expr = 2.96652814643838*sin(x) + 3.11758737898895*sin(2*x)
>>> from sympy.core.rules import Transform
>>> expr.xreplace(Transform(lambda x: x.round(2), lambda x: isinstance(x, Float)))
2.97*sin(x) + 3.12*sin(2*x)
```

Comment: Transform is a nicer way than extracting atoms, building a replacement dictionary and then doing the xreplace.

Comment: Not work for me, my code:

class Statistika:
    def syarat(self, K=None, C=None) -> None:

                if not C:
            C = symbols('Panjang_kelas');

        syms = self.pretty(solve(Eq(C, J/K), dict=1));
        C = syms[0][-1];
        print(f"C = {self.bulatkan(C)}");

stat.syarat(J=100, K=50)